I need to calculate the week number of a specific date
I need to calculate the week of a specific date. This is not working for me:
=WEEKNUM([Target Date],1)


Are you getting any error while using the formula or are you not getting the expected results?

I agree with Ganesh. I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance. If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Unfortunately, WEEKNUM function is not supported in SharePoint calculated formulas.
Check the list of supported functions at: Examples of common formulas in SharePoint lists.
Check solutions given in below threads which will help you to find the week number based on the date column in SharePoint list/library:

Formula calculated column: show date as week number
In SharePoint list online, get a week number from a date
Calculated field for Week Number not working for certain Sundays
Calculate the week from a date, Jan 1st = week 1
SharePoint Online: Calculated field with week number starting Saturday


Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

